# Julia MAC Installation

Tags: macos, julia

I am trying to install Julia on my MAC. I came up with the following error during installation:

[image]

Any idea is appreciated  about what the problem can be.

Edit:
"test.jl is like this:

```
using JuMP
using Gurobi
m = Model(solver=GurobiSolver())



m = Model()

@variable(m, x )              # No bounds
@variable(m, x >= lb )        # Lower bound only (note: 'lb <= x' is not valid)
@variable(m, x <= ub )        # Upper bound only
@variable(m, lb <= x <= ub )  # Lower and upper bounds
@variable(m, x == fixedval )  # Fixed to a value (lb == ub)

@variable(m, x[1:M,1:N] >= 0 )

aff = AffExpr([x, z], [3.0, 4.0], 2.0)  # 3x + 4z + 2
quad = QuadExpr([x,y],[x,z],[3.0,4.0],aff)  # 3x^2 + 4yz + 3x + 4z + 2

@constraints(m, begin
  x >= 1
  y - w <= 2
  sum_to_one[i=1:3], z[i] + y == 1
end)

@expression(m, shared, sum(i*x[i] for i=1:5))
@constraint(m, shared + y >= 5)
@constraint(m, shared + z <= 10)

expr = @expression(m, [i=1:3], i*sum(x[j] for j=1:3))
```

Comment: what is test.jl supposed to be?

Comment: This isn't an installation problem? It looks like Julia is installed, works, and even installed libraries. What is test.jl?

Comment: agreed, it looks like Julia simply cannot find where you put `test.jl`, which is not an installation problem

Comment: So, do you think the path is wrong? "Test.jl" is the short Julia code  that we want to test, which looks like this:

Comment: I am thinking the people who rate the question minus does not know Julia and are not eager to help. otherwise I am not sure I understand why you would be so uncomfortable with a question.

Comment: Maybe It is downvoted because they think you did not try hard enough to answer the question on your own?  It seems like the file test.jl that you have written is simply not in the directory you are trying to load it from.  Double check which directory it is in.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you that we tried this within a study group and I think even if I was not careful enough- or maybe at sleeping mode- some other people would warn us the file is not actually saved on Desktop. Is it possible "Desktop" has longer path than we see on Mac?

Comment: "Desktop"? "Downloads"? Have a read of the [survival guide](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Unix_SurvivalGuide.html) perhaps...

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:
- use the full path in your code to be sure where the file is located
- Julia is case sensitive, so Test.jl and test.jl are different
- check the permissions on the file
- Julia makes heavy use of "test.jl" type names, potential confusion?